# Simplify if-statements in function

Tags: if-statement, haskell

The following function includes multiple if-then-else statements. Is it possible to simplify the code without using the inner if-then-else statement?

```
f x y z = if y >= 15 
            then (if y < 23 then x*5 else f (x+4) (y+7) z) 
            else f(x+4) (y+7) z
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
f x y z
  | y >=15 && y < 23 = x*5
  | otherwise = f(x+4) (y+7) z
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am haskell beginner. Do u have any advice for practicing functions in general?

Comment: there is a good free haskell book for beginners. I'm not a big fan but its easy for beginners: http://learnyouahaskell.com